# How to rearrange the fermions in CohFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory

A simple question about notation of [Moore Nekrasov and Shatashvili](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9803265) which makes me confused. Page 3, the authors rearranged the action into a novel form.

For D=3+1,5+1,9+1 respectively, the path integral is
$$
I_D=(\frac{\pi}{g})^{\frac{(N^2-1)(D-3)}{2}} \frac{1}{{\rm{Vol(G)}}}\int d^DXd^{\frac{D}{2}-1}\Psi e^{-S} $$
where $S=\frac{1}{g}(\frac{1}{4}\Sigma {\rm{Tr}}[X_\mu,X_\nu]^2+\frac{i}{2}\Sigma {\rm{Tr}}(\bar{\Psi}\Gamma^\mu[X_\mu,\Psi]))$

The authors rearrange the fields into the following form:
$$ \phi=X_D+iX_{D-1} \\
B_j=X_{2j-1}+iX_{2j} ~~~~~~(\rm{for ~~~j=1,2...D/2-1})\\
\Psi \rightarrow \Psi_a=(\psi_j,\psi_j^{\dagger}), \vec{\chi
},\eta$$
$B_j$ are often denoted as $\mathbf{X}=\{X_a, a=1,....D-2\}$

My question is what the rearrangement of fermion field means? For D=4, a=2, j=1 ,$\chi$ has one component, before arrangement, we have a Dirac spinor $\Psi$, and what do we have after arrangement? are $\chi$ and $\eta$ Weyl spinors?

If we expand formula (2.4) using nilpotent symmetry (2.3), why no such terms like $\chi^{\dagger}[\bullet,\bullet]$?

**Edit:** From some related paper [Kazakov Kostov and Nekrasov](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9810035v2), the rearrangement is clear while there are some other puzzles. From KKN, first rewrite matrix model into complex fermion form, which is the formula (2.1) of KKN
$$\frac{1}{\rm{Vol(G)}}\int dXd\lambda \exp(\frac{1}{2}\Sigma _{\mu<\nu}\rm{Tr}[X_\mu,X_\nu]^2+ )+\rm{Tr}\bar{\lambda}_\dot{\alpha}\sigma_\mu^{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}[X_\mu,\lambda_\alpha]$$ 
Two complex fermions $\lambda$  can be written as four real fermions $\chi$, $\eta$,$\psi_\alpha$, $\alpha=1,2$,
$$ \lambda_1=\frac{1}{2}(\eta-i\chi),\\
\lambda_2=\frac{1}{2}(\psi_1+\psi_2),\\
\bar{\lambda}_{\dot{a}} =\sigma_2^{a\dot{a}}\lambda_a^*,~~~s=[X_1,X_2]$$
Using the following nilpotent symmetry:
$$ \delta X_\alpha=\psi_\alpha,~~~\delta\psi_\alpha=[\phi,X_\alpha] ,\\
\delta\bar{\phi}=\eta,~~~\delta \eta [\phi,\bar{\phi}],\\
\delta\chi=H,~~~\delta H=[\phi,\chi],\\
\delta \phi=0$$

KKN claims that the action can be written as formula (2.5),
$$ S=\delta \left( -i\rm{Tr} \chi s -\frac{1}{2} \rm{Tr}\chi H - \Sigma_a\psi_a[X_a,\bar{\phi}] -\frac{1}{2} \eta[\phi,\bar{\phi}]\right) $$

I found that there is some inconsistence between formula (2.1) and formula (2.5).
Look at fermionic part that consist $X_2$ in (2.5) which is proportional to $i\rm{Tr} \chi[\psi_1,X_2] + \rm{Tr}\psi_2[X_2,\eta] $. If we start from (2.1), fermionic part that consist $X_2$ should be proportional to $ \bar{\lambda}_\dot{1}\sigma_2^{2\dot{1}}[X_2,\lambda_2] +\bar{\lambda}_\dot{2}\sigma_2^{1\dot{2}}[X_2,\lambda_1] $. Further using definition of $\bar{\lambda}_\dot{a}=\sigma_2^{a\dot{a}}\lambda_a^*$, we always get terms of form $\lambda_1^*[X_2,\lambda_1]$ and  $\lambda_2^*[X_2,\lambda_2]$ which can not consist  $i\rm{Tr} \chi[\psi_1,X_2] + \rm{Tr}\psi_2[X_2,\eta] $.

Anything wrong here? Some comments and references are welcoming.

Comment: It's analogous to a decomposition of the spinor etc. under the $U(N)$ subgroup of $O(2N)$ - note that you paired the bosonic spacetime coordinates to complex coordinates. Try to figure out how the spinor decomposes in the three dimensionalities.

Comment: I have revised the question.